# Form validation logic and error message for iPhone client

Tags: iphone, validation, error-handling

In iPhone I have a register form composed of many `UITextField`. Now I have no validation on any of them and leave this to server to send me back errors messages.

The problem is how should I formatted error message from server. It used to be 

`{
  email: ["email must be valid", "list of error message for this field"],
  another_field: ["list of error message for this field"],
  ...
}`

which is perfectly fine for showing error messages in html form, but not quite useful for iPhone.

My question is how should I formatted this errors message to be use for iPhone or should I replicate validation logic into my app for flexible customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Server side or client side validation logic is up to you depending on your situation and there are pro's and cons of each.  In general I would recommend client side validation for a few reasons:

- API calls introduce problems of their own.  What if it fails?
- There is latency involved with the call.  I don't want a user to type something or push a button and 2 seconds later something pops up to tell me my age is too young or something like that.
- API calls use data that folks are paying for.  Yes it's not a lot of data but every bit counts.
- In general most of the validation logic I end up doing is fairly simple.  Things more complicated like email can be tackled with regex.

That's just a few off the top of my head.  Of course some things can't be done on the client such as checking for an available username.  In this case you'll have to decide how much data from your error message you want to display to your user.  In this case it looks like you have JSON and given that JSON can be recursive (dictionaries inside dictionaries or arrays inside arrays) you can write a recursive function to format it (if you want all of it of course).  The other option is to have deterministic values in the JSON that you can query for and display to the user.